# Not able to test Cassandra execcuteAsync response

Tags: java, junit, cassandra

Here is my sample original method

```
public void insertIntoDb(SampleObject sample){
      ---------------------------------------
      ---------------------------------------
      code to prepare Insert statement
      ---------------------------------------
      ---------------------------------------
      session.executeAsync(insertStatement);
}
```

I am writing a test method for the above method

```
public void insertIntoDbTest(){
      --------------------------------------
      ---------------------------------------
      preparing SampleObject and checking the size of the corresponding table before insert
      ---------------------------------------
      ---------------------------------------
      obj.insertIntoDb(sampleObject)

      ---------------------------------------
      checking the size of the corresponding table after insert
      ---------------------------------------
}
```

Expectation: After executing above test method, 1 extra row should be added to table in cassandra, i.e If before insert table size : 0 then after insert Table size : 1

Actual: I am getting same size i.e size of the table before and after is 0 only.

If I replace

`session.executeAsync(insertStatement);`

with

`ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(insertStatement);`

then add below statement

`future.get()`

then I am getting difference in size of the table i.e 1

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the computation (insert) is not complete when you first try to verify the table size.

The `ResultSetFuture get()` method waits, if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

The `executeAsync` method does not wait.

It returns as soon as the query has been passed to the underlying network stack. In particular, returning from this method does not guarantee that the query is valid or has even been submitted to a live node. Any exception pertaining to the failure of the query will be thrown when accessing the ResultSetFuture. Source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSetFuture.html

Comment: I cant change the original method functionality

Comment: You can try to add `Thread.sleep(60000)` before your verification, so your test will wait 1 minute before checks data is inserted. This is not the nicest solution though and might still fail depending on your Cassandra setup and configuration.

Comment: I already tried to use `Thread.sleep()` even I took 2mins also its not working

Answer (score 1):

future.get() is a blocking code so it makes sure the async thread executes and returns response. In your case it will make sure it will insert a record that is why you are getting size of 1 when you assert after calling future.get() and if you don't invoke the get() then it will be async you might have to call future.complete() in this case there will be two scenarios one with exception and one without it and return type of this method will be Future<> Object which you have to handle somewhere above your method call trace.

Comment: I cant change the original method functionality